# Connecting angular encoder to an INTERRUPT to count cycles

Tags: gpio, python

I'm building a Robotic Car, the 4 DC Motors are working perfectly. I need to know the speed of its moving using an Encoder.

> **Encoder that I use:** has two edges (transmitter & receiver) and a holed circle (has 30 hole) attached to the motor, so the Encoder give a digital pulse when a the signal from transmitter to receiver is cut.

I know that there is a better solution to have an accurate value of velocity (e.g. using an IMU or an aceleromoter) but I'm totally newbie, and after a long search I found that using IMU is so difficult, and it has no implementation using Python. That's why I have chosen to use Encoders.

Many Thanks for any suggestion or help, my project should be finished within one week

Comment: DId you mean "Wheel counter" which uses photo interrupter?

Comment: So?  Count the pulses in a known period.  Divide by 30 to get the revolutions.  Multiply by the wheel diameter times pi to get the distance.  What problem are you having?

Comment: Mr. @joan the problem not in counting pulse ... **1.** I need to trig an event whenever the car moves that require the Encoder to be connected as an interrupt. **2.** I need to subtract revolutions when car moves backward.

Comment: You need to edit clarifications into your question.